# Challenge: Android Display Splitting

Tags: android, video, resolution, low-level, hdmi

This is my first post here at Stack Overflow, and it’s a doozy!

I'm hoping some good people with low-level android experience may be of help--perhaps with some places to start and/or comments on the feasibility of my goals. It’s for something really cool (a first-of-it's-kind consumer technology). I promise I’ll pay the help forward!

**Goals:**

- Intercept Android video output via HDMI, MHL, etc.
- If possible, increase the resolution to 150% of the original width (see why below):
- Unfortunately I can't post images yet, but the left half of the external screen needs to adopt the left 3/4 of the chosen output resolution, while the right half needs to adopt the right 3/4 of the chosen output resolution. (image link: i.imgur.com[forwardslash]2WxFMiJ.png)

**But wait- that's three halves! Won’t that look strange?**

- To the naked eye, yes. Some proven technology of ours will help the user’s brain meld these together into one image.
- Ideally the Android device can output a resolution 150% the original width so that the “joined” image keeps its original aspect.

**Research I’ve Done:**

- All the S.O. questions I found on android HDMI did not involve modifying the output stream. Some mention old dead links to Motorola developer pages, and every path there turned up dry :(
- I’ve read through the SDK documentation on Display, [DisplayManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.html), and [Presentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html), but not much seems to go low enough or give me access to the manipulation I need.

**Things I’ve considered:**

- Perhaps some Unity 3D fanciness for video playback (the primary usage case), as its built-in cameras provide a nice way to work with multiple views.
- Perhaps not… Maybe it can be done with the standard ADT bundle?

**Wouldn’t it be nice?**

... if it were as simple as

```
    Rect standardRect = defaultViewport.dimensions;
    Display leftDisplay = new Display(defaultViewport, new Point(0, 0), new Rect(standardRect.x*(.75), standardRect.y));
    Display rightDisplay = new Display(defaultViewport, new Point(standardRect.x*.25, 0),new Rect(standardRect.x*(.75), standardRect.y));
```

**Thank you all**

... for your help now and the collective wisdom I've so often tapped into here.

For completeness, there is a parallel discussion going on at my other favorite forums... XDA! [.../showthread.php?p=46711747]

Comment: 1. If its just the output that is transformed - can't it go into a PC/Laptop?2

Comment: 2. I don't think that typical Android devices can output different content than what is on the screen. If you want the Android screen to have your format - consider rendering the video to two different textures (ffmpeg?)

Comment: @MorrisonChang 
Firstly, thanks for giving this some thought and taking the time to answer!

1. The goal is to have a standalone system that involves just the android and this external screen, so a PC/Laptop is not an option.

2. I haven't explored this option. I'll poke around a bit, but do you know off the top of your head where I may be able to start?